# Proving that a function from $R^{n+1}-{0\}$ to $S^n$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, continuity, spheres

Given the function $f: R^{n+1}- \{0\} \rightarrow S^n$ defined by $f(x)= \dfrac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}$, prove that $f(x)$ is continuous.

I have tried to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}, S^n$ are metric spaces, so that I can use an epsilon-delta proof.

However, I was not able to get to the last part of the inequality

$$ \left\Vert\frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}-\frac{x_0}{\Vert x_0\Vert}\right\Vert.$$

I am open to another method.

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: Hmm, since $\mathbf{0}\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, what is $f(\mathbf{0})$? Do you mean the domain to be $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{\mathbf{0}\}$?

Comment: If you haven't done this already, take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on how to ask a good question, and in particular look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) for the importance of providing context, including perhaps your own work, what you already know about the question, and so on. As it stands, you are simply demanding that we give you a proof. Such demands attract close votes and down votes.

Comment: MPW- yes I have tried to look at the proof for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}, \mathbb{R}-\{0\} \rightarrow S^1$. However, this proof does not translate for $n \geq 1$

Answer (score 1):

Scalar multiplication is continuous as a map $s: \Bbb R \times \Bbb R^{n+1} \to \Bbb R^{n+1}, s(t,x)=t \cdot x$. This follows by inequalities like

$\|t\cdot x - t'\cdot x'\|  =\|(t\cdot x - t'\cdot x) + (t' \cdot x - t' \cdot x)\| \le |t-t'| \cdot \|x\| + |t'|\|x- x'\|$, from which we can show that whenever $t_n \to t_0$ in $\Bbb R$ and $x_n \to x_0$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ we also have $t_n \cdot x_n \to t_0 \cdot x_0$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ as well.

Also the norm map is continuous from $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ to $\Bbb R$ so if $x_n \to x_0$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$, we have that $\|x_n\| \to \|x_0\|$ and as $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous from $(0,\infty)$ to $\Bbb R$, we also have $\frac{1}{\|x_n\|} \to \frac{1}{\|x_0\|}$ and then applying the first fact about scalar multiplication, $f(x_n) = \frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|} = \frac{1}{\|x_n\|} \cdot x_n \to \frac{1}{\|x_0\|} \cdot x_0 = \frac{x_0}{\|x_0\|} =f(x_0)$. QED.

We don't need sequences (but they suffice), and can also write $f$ as a  composition of continuous maps instead. But that's the basic idea: norm, and scalar multiplication on $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ and inversion on the reals are all continuous and $f$ is a combination of these operations.

Comment: Thanks I see, nice use of composition of functions.